# is_file($_GET) and security

Tags: php, file-io, get

I'm using this code on top of my PHP file for loading cached files and I'm worried whether it's secure enough:

```
//quick! load from cache if exists!
if (is_file('cache/'.($cachefile=basename('/',$_GET['f']))))
{
    header('content-type: text/css');
    require('cache/'.$cachefile);
    die(); //ALL OK, loaded from cache
}
```

**EDIT:** I would also like to know if it isn't, how is it exploitable and how to rewrite it in safe manner.

**EDIT 2:** I edited code, from previous code, I don't know how I could thought that `is_file` will filter bad paths >.<

**EDIT 3:** Changed it again, so it uses `basename()` instead of `end(explode())` and also changed inclusion from repeating the code into assigning the value into variable during first comparison (or file check).

I never just `include($_GET)`, but today, I somehow thought `is_file` will filter out paths, that may harm my system. I don't know how.

Thank you

Comment: basename() will do the thing smoother. But never duplicate your code. use a variable.

Comment: Workable, but `end(explode('/',...))` is a real kludge in comparison to `basename()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could send `$_GET['f'] = '../../database_passwords.xml'` ...

Use `basename` to eliminate anything but the last segment of the passed path. Alternatively, construct the path, then compute the absolute path that corresponds and check if it's still within `cache/`.

Comment: I changed the code a bit, might check it out and see if it's better?

Answer (score 2):

BAD!

What about:

```
page.php?f=../../../../../etc/password
```

Never do such things

Check f against a white list or specific pattern like "[a-z]+.php"

Comment: Thank you, please, see comment above :)

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't. I could put `'../../anypath'` in `$_GET['f']` and gain access to any file on your server, even those outside your www root.

[edit]
It would be a lot safer if you would check for '/' and other invalid characters in the value. It is pretty safe if that filename only contains alphanumeric characters and `.` and `_`.

Comment: I did something close to checking for '/', is it better?